# How to make serialize missing fields in JSON String with jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am reading a JSON String where every field is optional and i need to either get the values from config or set it to a default value.

Say my JSON is -

```
{
"action": {
           "onWarning":{
               "alert":{
                      "isEnabled": true,
                    "name": "DVS.sd_service.data-validation.bigdata.warning"
                       }
               },
           "onError":{
             "alert":{
                    "isEnabled": false,
                    "name": "DVS.sd_service.data-validation.bigdata.error"
                    }
               }
         }
}
```

And my code to read this JSON is -

```
    mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
    mapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
    JobConfig jobConfig = mapper.readValue(contentJson, JobConfig.class);
```

And below are my wrapper classes -

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class JobConfig {
    public Optional<AlertConfig> action;
}

@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class AlertWrapper {
    public Optional<Alert> alert;
}

@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class AlertConfig {
    public Optional<AlertWrapper> onSuccess;
    public Optional<AlertWrapper> onWarning;
    public Optional<AlertWrapper> onError;
}

@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Alert{
    public Optional<Boolean> isEnabled;
    public Optional<String> name;
}
```

Now the objective here is to read `OnError.alert.isEnabled` however if this field or the entire `onError` part is not available then we have to set it to default **True**

The function i have written for this is :-

```
private Optional<Boolean> getErrorIsEnabled(JobConfig jobConfig ) {
        Optional<Boolean> isEnabled = Optional.empty();
        if(jobConfig.action.isPresent()) {
            if(jobConfig.action.get().onError.isPresent()){
                if(jobConfig.action.get().onError.get().alert.isPresent()) {
                    if(jobConfig.action.get().onError.get().alert.get().isEnabled.isPresent()){
                        isEnabled= jobConfig.action.get().onError.get().alert.get().isEnabled;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return isEnabled;
    }
```

This way i get to find if the vale is available in config by calling the above function -

```
getErrorIsEnabled(jobConfig).orElse(true)
```

The problem is (calling the above function) this works but looks way too ugly to keep on checking if the fields are ***available or not at every level*** by calling the `isPresent()` funtion.

The User can entirely skip the `OnError` Part, or `action` Part, or just the `alert` part, or the `alert.isEnabled` part. There has to be a better way to acieve this! Open to suggestions or improvements or try a different approach alltogether.

Comment: Why is every field an `Optional`, for example, why `public Optional<Boolean> isEnabled` instead of `public Boolean isEnabled = true`?

Comment: Because otherwise, it returns NullPointerException when i directly call this field and it is unavailable in the JSON. To fix that, i had to make it Optional :|

Comment: Also, the requirement for the name filed has to be same but the default value here is calculated dynamically, so it can't be just = SomeString

Comment: @Paul Just changed as you mentioned above and calling `jobConfig.action.get().onWarning.get().alert.get().isEnabled` gives null and `jobConfig.action.get().onWarning.get().alert.get().isEnabled.value` gives NullPointerException.

Comment: Instead of accessing the fields directly make them private and use getters and setters for access and to return sensible (non-`Optional`) defaults.  Don't call `jobConfig.action` but `jobConfig.getAction()` which would return the `AlertConfig` set by Jackson or a new/default `AlertConfig`.  If you don't want to deal with nulls then have each getter return a new or default instance if the field has not been set.

Comment: Even with the above approach to decide if i have to send value set by Jackson or default, i will have to do the same thing in getter, which is checking every variable if it is set ot now. Is it? It's just the logic will be disrtibuted across multiple getters.

Comment: Also we have to conside the fact that, default value sometimes is decided dynamically so i can't do it in getter setter, it has to be done only after knowing if it it set or not.

Comment: My point is that each object should return defaults if that is possible and desired.  It's not a matter of where the logic is.  If null is an allowed value then yes, you will need to check for nulls.  Or decide that getters will never return null.  Or use Groovy and avoid NPEs via the [safe navigation operator](https://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_safe_navigation_operator).

Comment: Thanks @Paul, Changing `@ AllArgsConstructor ` to  `@NoArgsConstructor` and writing constructors to initialize all objects with Default objects, helped me fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is create default values for the fields like

```
private Optional<Boolean> isEnabled = Optional.empty();
private Optional<String> name = Optional.empty();

public Alert(Optional<Boolean> isEnabled , Optional<String> name){
    this.isEnabled=isEnabled;
    this.name=name;
}
```

And for every Object like this -

```
private final Alert alertDetail = new Alert(Optional.empty(), Optional.empty());
    private final AlertWrapper alertWrapper = new AlertWrapper(alertDetail);


    private AlertWrapper onSuccess = alertWrapper;
    private AlertWrapper onWarning = alertWrapper;
    private AlertWrapper onError = alertWrapper;
```

You will have to create constructor so you will have to change your lombok to `@NoArgsConstructor` also use `@Getter @Setter` so you can call your objects like below  -

```
jobConfig.getAction().getOnWarning().getAlert().getIsEnabled().orElse(true)
```